# interface & integer comparison in golang

Tags: go

I don't understand why the first result is false while second is true.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
func main() {
    var i interface{}

    i = uint64(0)
    fmt.Println("[1] ", reflect.TypeOf(i), i == 0)

    i = 0
    fmt.Println("[2] ", reflect.TypeOf(i), i == 0)

    var n uint64 = 32
    fmt.Println("[3] ", reflect.TypeOf(n), n == 32) 
}

// result
// [1]  uint64 false
// [2]  int true
// [3]  uint64 true
```

Try it here [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pJEU8bl9s5)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `0` is an untyped constant whose default type is `int`, not `uint64`, and when doing comparison with an interface, the thing you are comparing to must be both the same type and the same value for them to be considered equal.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators

> The equality operators == and != apply to operands that are comparable. The ordering operators <, <=, >, and >= apply to operands that are ordered. These terms and the result of the comparisons are defined as follows:
>
> A value x of non-interface type X and a value t of interface type T are comparable when values of type X are comparable and X implements T. They are equal if t's dynamic type is identical to X and t's dynamic value is equal to x.

Comment: Why can you use type assertion such as `i.(uint64) == 0`? Does the compiler assume `0` is a `uint64` too? https://play.golang.org/p/YT-pZCdI27

Comment: Once you do a type assertion, you are no longer comparing an interface with a value, you are comparing a value with a value, so you lose the requirement of their dynamic types needing to be equal.